What is the difference between a matrix normal distribution and the multivariate gaussian distribution?
$\newcommand{\vec}{\operatorname{vec}}$Consider a set of $N$ matrices $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$. I want to estimate the distribution of these matrices represented by the mean and covariance.
I address this problem by simply vectorizing my matrices $\vec(X_1), \vec(X_2), \ldots, \vec(X_N)$, then I compute the mean and covariance as I would for a multivariate Gaussian distribution. In other words, this implies that $\vec(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(M, \Sigma)$ where $\vec(X)$ is reshaped to get $X$ after sampling
However, I came across matrix normal distributions, which defines the distribution based on the row covariance and column covariance. So, a matrix sampled from a matrix normal distribution is given by $X \sim \mathcal{M}\mathcal{N}(M, U, V)$.
In the wikipedia article, it says that the relation between the matrix normal distribution and the multivariate gaussian distribution for a random matrix $X$ is $X \sim \mathcal{M}\mathcal{N}(M, U, V)$ if and only if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(V \otimes U)$ where $\otimes$ is the operator for the kronecker product.
If I generate a set of random matrices, I can estimate the parameters of the distribution in multiple ways. I can vectorize my matrices as treat as a multivariate Gaussian to get the covariance. Or, I can compute the row covariance and column covariance, then I can compute the covariance from the kronecker product.
However, I am not getting the same values for the covariance from the vectorized approach verses the kronecker product approach. Should I get the same result for each? If not, why are they different? I don't understand what these distributions represent in practice, so I not sure which should be used in which scenario.

How are you estimating $U$ and $V$ from the samples? Are you using iterative maximum likelihood (as presented here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_parameter_estimation)? Are you estimating $\Sigma$ via vanilla maximum likelihood?

@JohandeAguas I estimate $U$ and $V$ using the iterative approach in the link you provided. If vectoring and representing as a multivariate gaussian, I use vanilla mle.

Check out:
Dawid, A. Philip. "Some matrix-variate distribution theory: notational considerations and a Bayesian application." Biometrika 68.1 (1981): 265-274.

Example for diagonal matrices $$U = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & 0 & 0 \\0& u_2 & 0 \\ 0&0&u_3 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & 0 & 0 \\0& v_2 & 0 \\ 0&0&v_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
lead to $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} u_1v_1 & 0 &0&0 &0&0&0&0&0\\
0&u_1v_2 & 0 &0&0 &0&0&0&0\\
0&0&u_1v_3 & 0 &0 &0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&u_2v_1 & 0 &0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&u_2v_2 & 0 &0&0 &0\\
0&0&0&0&0&u_2v_3 & 0 &0 &0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&u_3v_1 & 0 &0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&u_3v_2 & 0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&u_3v_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
the $2n$ values in $U$ and $V$ will lead to $n^2$ values in $\Sigma$.
So if you estimate those values in $\Sigma$ directly instead of $U \otimes V$, the you will have a larger degree of possible values and the estimates will be different.
The same is true for non diagonal matrices. The matrix normal distribution restricts the parameterization of the $n^4$ values in $\Sigma$ to the $2n^2$ values in $U$ and $V$.

Thanks for this answer. What are the implications of limiting to $2n^2$ values? I suppose I don't quite understand the practical meaning of the row covariance and column covariance as well as the overall covariance computed from these. For example, this isn't just a compressed version of covariance, but instead, it has a different meaning overall, right?

@Ralff I don't know much about this distribution, but the Wikipedia page mentions under related distributions a Wishart distribution (and an article by David). A Wishart distribution with a diagonal scale matrix has variance like u_i*v_j. This matrix normal distribution is possibly an approximation.
